# redirect to subfolder and remove subfolder name in url htacces

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I know this question is so noob but I'm new in htaccess.

```
public_html  
    --htaccess  
    --myfolder  
        --htaccess
```

I installed my wp inside myfolder, in my first htacccess I put

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^myfolder/ /myfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

My problem is when I click my links, url is displayed in this form

```
www.mywebsite.com/myfolder/page/
```

how can I make it in a form of

```
www.mywebsite/page/
```

I did not put anyting in htaccess inside myfolder.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: wordpress files located in your public_html or myfolder? i think it is located in myfolder thats why it showing myfolder in url

Comment: Yes, I installed my wordpress in myfolder. Thank you for your clarification

Comment: I solved this problem using permalink under settings in wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in myfolder .htaccess file so that it will redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

> www.mywebsite.com/myfolder/page/

to

> www.mywebsite.com/page/

you can delete first .htaccess file located in your /public_html

Comment: After I deleted the htaccess file public_html, I used your code and  the result is 404 
    http://mywebsite.com/home/domain/public_html/myfolder/myfolder